# MATLAB code Modelling Cell Replication and Death

Tags: matlab, statistics, probability

We start with 1 cell. It can replicate at rate (exponential rate) 1 and die at rate 1. Let Y denote the number of cells. The first event (death or replication) happens at rate 2. If it's death -> we stop since we have 0 cells. 
If it's replication -> we update time to t+tau, and the next event now happens at rate 4. (since 2 cells can replicate or die).

Since only 2 events can occur, the probability of death occurring is 1/(1+1) for one cell, 2/(2+2) for 2 cells and so on, and also the same for replication. This is why we draw a random number from 0 to 2. If this number is >1 then a cell dies, otherwise it replicates.

> Intuitively, at least half of the times the cell should die and hence
>   the probability of 0 cells at time 3 should be P(Y=0)>0.5 (in fact the
>   answer is 3/4). But when I put this code into a for loop and run it
>   1000 times, I get the number of times Y=0 to be around 400 which is
>   0.4

```
t=0;
rr=1; %rate of replication 1 cell -> 2 cells
rd=1; %rate of death 1 cell -> 0 cells
Y=1; %initial number of cells
while t<3 && Y>0 % interested in probabilities of number of cells at time t=0,t=1,t=2,t=3
    r = 2*rand; %draws a random number from 0 to 2
    tau=exprnd(2*Y); %since the total rate of all possible events is replication+death=2 for each cell
    if t+tau < 3 %if the event happens before 3 seconds
        if r>1 %death
        Y=Y-1;
        else Y=Y+1; %otherwise replication
        end 
    elseif t+tau > 3 %if the next event happens after 3 seconds, we are not interested.
        Y; 
        t; 
        break
        end;
    t=t+tau; %update time from t to t+tau
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, before running into a debugging proccess, check your statistics!

By Central Limit theorem, if we define y as the random variable with y=1 when Y=0 and y=0 otherwise, then the average over N runs of y should be converging to P(Y=0) in mean, and std(y)/sqrt(N) in variance. So I would

- Return a couple of times on the 1,000 runs and see how the results vary.
- Check if with 10^5 runs it behaves better.
- Calculate std(y) exactly, or at least bound it.

If all of these fail, then its probably a bug.

Comment: I've done it with 100,000 runs and it doesn't converge. I dont know what has gone wrong

Comment: I didn't quite understand the way you calculated P(Y=0), and I'm not sure its right. Try to write it formally...

Comment: Number of times Y turned out to be 0 divided by the number of runs. I think I fixed the problem by rolling tau using exponential 1/2Y rate istead of 2Y. Then the results agree. I don't understand why just yet, but its a different question